# Handle Excel Special Characters using Java

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, special-characters

I have a form that allows users to enter in a long legal text.  It is likely that users will copy and paste from an Excel and/or a PDF file.  I have run into an issue with Special Characters and I have put

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
```

at the top of my jsp page. However, I'm seeing special characters in the text.

For example, in the Excel file there is the following description:

"...Rentee will pay the Rentor...***_*** all of the rent by a *_* of the month"

The "..." is being translated into ┬à (a with a left-to-right tilde). How can I replace those special characters with "..." as one can see in Excel?

Comment: To me, `  String text= "...Rentee will pay the Rentor..._ all of the rent by a _ of the month";
  System.out.println(text);
` is working fine. It prints the same text. Can you please share the code, how are your reading and storing/printing?

Comment: Here is part of the text from the file: "… Rentee shall pay Rentor as as appropriate… all of the rent by a ___ of the month"  The dots at the beginning and after 'appropriate' are not periods but special characters from Excel.  When doing a system.println it comes out as ├ó┬Ç┬ª

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar problems with people copy / pasting Microsoft "smart quotes" into forms and wondering why they don't render or store correctly later.  I made use of the fairly small and straightforward jasciidamnit library to clean these characters out from any input.  [Give the library a shot, see if it solves your problem](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasciidammit/)

Comment: Thank you. I tried this tool but it seems to not be able to handle the ├ó┬Ç┬ª from Excel

Comment: Hey David, thanks.  This is being used during our testing phase and I haven't heard any complaints yet.  Thanks for the tip.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the ellipsis `"..."` is being copied at a single Unicode character (u+2026 or '…').  You should be setting the pageEncoding to UTF-8 because that is what you are sending.

Comment: Yep I tried changing the pageEncoding to UTF-8, I'm still getting ├ó┬Ç┬ª in my system.out.println before inserting into an Oracle CLOB field.

Comment: If you're printing it to a console that's what you will get.  The console is NOT a browser, and uses only ISO-8859 even if you send it UTF-8.